# Find the associated values of a vector in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a reference dataframe `df` which determines the relationship between a number code and the name associated to it.

```
df <- data.frame(Number = 1:5,
                 Name = c("Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc", "Ddd", "Eee"))
```

Now, I have a vector of numbers `number <- c(1,1,3,5,6)` and I want to get their corresponding `Name`, taking into account that:

- There are repeated numbers
- Some of the numbers may not have an associated name in the table

So, the result I expect is:

```
df2 <- data.frame(number,
                  Name = c("Aaa", "Aaa", "Ccc", "Eee", NA))
```

The vector of numbers I have is very long, any idea about how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> df$Name[match(number,df$Number)]
[1] "Aaa" "Aaa" "Ccc" "Eee" NA
```

Comment: Thank you! That is just what I was looking for. I did not know the `match` function.

Answer (score 4):

If performance is the issue ("The vector of numbers I have is very long") one potential option is to use data.table, e.g.

```r
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(Number = 1:5,
                 Name = c("Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc", "Ddd", "Eee"))

number <- c(1,1,3,5,6)
number_df <- as.data.frame(number)

setDT(df)
setDT(number_df)

number_df[df, name:=Name, on=.(number=Number)]
number_df
#>    number name
#> 1:      1  Aaa
#> 2:      1  Aaa
#> 3:      3  Ccc
#> 4:      5  Eee
#> 5:      6 <NA>

df2 <- data.table(number,
                  name = c("Aaa", "Aaa", "Ccc", "Eee", NA))
all.equal(number_df, df2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can make your `number` vector as a dataframe, then `left_join` with the original `df`.

```r
library(dplyr)

left_join(data.frame(Number = number), df, by = "Number")

  Number Name
1      1  Aaa
2      1  Aaa
3      3  Ccc
4      5  Eee
5      6 <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a good answer for that particular example

Answer (score 3):

A base R option, using `merge`

```
> merge(data.frame(Number = number), df, all.x = TRUE)
  Number Name
1      1  Aaa
2      1  Aaa
3      3  Ccc
4      5  Eee
5      6 <NA>
```

or as @GKi's solution in the comment

```
> merge(df, number, by.x = "Number", by.y = 1, all.y = TRUE)
  Number Name
1      1  Aaa
2      1  Aaa
3      3  Ccc
4      5  Eee
5      6 <NA>
```

Comment: Or `merge(df, number, by.x="Number", by.y=1, all.y=TRUE)`

Comment: @GKi Really interesting use of `merge`! First time to see this. Thanks a lot!